# Как сделать решение в одну строку?

Tags: pascal

Вводится строка из 1, 2 и 3, сортируется в такой последовательности 132.

Comment: Так, задание понятно. А в чем заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Идея такая - сопоставить каждому из трёх символов некоторый ключ, по которому будет происходить сортировка.

```
begin
  ReadlnString().OrderBy(x ->
    begin
      case x of
        '1': Result := 1;
        '2': Result := 3;
        '3': Result := 2;
      end;
    end).Println();
end.
```

Можно использовать `?:` вместо `case .. of`, но мне понравился больше вариант с `case .. of`.

Comment: Не стоит бросаться отвечать на непонятные вопросы. Вопрос скорее всего будет закрыт и/или удален. Чтобы ответ не пропал - можете запостить вопрос про сортировку в Паскале (если ранее аналогичного не было) от своего имени и разместить ответ к нему.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Comment: var s,r,f,q:string; i:integer; 
begin 
readln(s); 
for i:=1 to Length(s) do begin 
if (s[i]='1') 
then r:=r+s[i]; 
if (s[i]='3') 
then f:=f+s[i]; 
if (s[i]='2') 
then q:=q+s[i]; 
end; 
writeln(r+f+q); 
end.
у меня есть такой алгоритм выполнения задачи, но нужно уместить это в одну строку